# Setting a style color based on an if/else

Tags: asp.net, html

```
<td nowrap valign="top">
<input class="formsubmit" id="btnGo" type="button" value="Show Description" 
style = "<%# If (DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Exclamation").ToString() == "1")
then Response.Write("color:red") 
Else Response.Write("color:black") EndIf%>" 
OnClick="btnShowDescription('<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ListingDescription")%>');" />
</td>
                        `
```

This is the code for a cell on my table. I'm trying to get it to work but there's a compiler issue saying that I'm missing a closed parentheses which I'm not. (hopefully). Can anyone see what the error could be? I thought I did the if/else logic right. Basically I'm trying to set the font color of a button based on what the value of a certain item in a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is because the `style=" "` is choking on the first double quote?

> style = "<%# If
>   (DataBinder.Eval(Container,
>   "**<--right here**  DataItem.Exclamation").ToString() ==
>   "1") then Response.Write("color:red") 
>   Else Response.Write("color:black")
>   EndIf%>"

Perhaps you need to escape one or more of the quotes?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the # in front of your If statement i.e. replace

style = "<%**#** If (DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Exclamation").ToString()

with

style = "<% If (DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Exclamation").ToString()

Answer (score 0):

use this..

```
style="<%#  (DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Exclamation").ToString() == "1") ? Response.Write("color:red") :Response.Write("color:red")  %>"
```

OR

```
style="<%# (Eval("Exclamation").ToString() == "1") ? Response.Write("color:red") :Response.Write("color:red")  %>
```